# How to create a temporary browser-side file with path in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, temporary

I have a **front-end** application in **Javascript**. I need to use a plug-in ([three.js](https://threejs.org/)) that as input needs a URL path to a file with `MTL` extension in order to work. In this application I make some data elaboration in order to generate the content of the `MTL` file to be then fed to the `three.js` plug-in. Everything needs to be done on the **front-end**, therefore I cannot access the file system to save the file. How can I create a temporary path and file with `MTL` extension in order to be passed to the `three.js` plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a file is possible only in IE using ActiveX objects.